# Specify custom zoom levels manually in CATiledLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

I have been trying for days to create CATiledLayer with custom zoom levels, similar to what [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView) does in android.

Here's the code used in android [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView): `addDetailLevel(zoomScale,Dimension,imageUrl/col_row)`

I've created a fully functioning project that has 2x zooms. For each zoom level CATiledLayer's `draw:` is being called, but require `draw:` to be called only at 4x steps.

[JCTiledScollView](https://github.com/yichizhang/JCTiledScrollView_Swift) and [TiledLayer](https://github.com/Fishinear/TiledLayer) libraries are being added. I've created a repository named [CATiledLayerTest](https://github.com/bibinjacobpulickal/CATiledLayerTest).

Maybe if someone could take a look you could find what I'm missing (project compactibility xcode 8, swift 3).

My implementation: 
CATiledLayer being returned as layer and contain tiles of dimension 256x256. This is implemented into UIScrollView minimum zoom level set to 1 max set to 4. Pinch zooming causes CATiledLayer to render new images at scale 2x. But I require new images to be rendered only at 4x.

Comment: There is too much code to post. I've posted the repository [link](https://github.com/bibinjacobpulickal/CATiledLayerTest).

Comment: CATiledLayer with image filled in each tile is rendered on UIScollView min zoom level is set to 1 max is 4. As I begin pinch zoom new CATiledLayer is being called. As soon as zoom passes value of 2x layer defined for 4x is rendered. I require the layer 4x to be rendered only upon reaching 4x zoom level.